# Android: CustomView Circle Stroke not smooth

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have following code in my onDraw method:

```
canvas.drawArc(rect, -90, 360, true, bgpaint);
if(isFocussed)
            canvas.drawArc(rect, -90, 360, true, strokePaint);
```

for strokePaint, this is what I have in my init() method:

```
strokePaint = new Paint();
strokePaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);        
strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
```

Whenever the strokePaint comes into play, the circular stroke is not smooth. The stroke is flat by little bit at top, bottom, left and right.

How do I fix this problem?

Screenshot of the problematic circle:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the stroke width in account when drawing.
Just make your shape smaller about half of it.

Though I can't say it for sure depending on your code, I just think that you are drawing outside of bounds of your view. That's a common issue.

Comment: Whole view? Could you add a screenshot? That would likely help to find out the root of your issue..

Comment: So, it indeed seems like an issue with your drawing coordinates..Try to make the `rect` you are passing as parameter to the `drawArc` method smaller.

Comment: It worked like a charm..how foolish I was...anyway..thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this `setAntiAlias(true)`and `setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)`

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Ok, you say that the stroke is flat by little bit at top, bottom, left and right, so maybe works...  `setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND)`

Comment: sorry, it still doesn't solve the problem. I have attached the screenshot for reference.

Comment: Thanks setAntiAlias(true) working fine for me